# Rendering of a button in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery mobile button renders gibberish for filter button after clicking on pagination.   Click event that shows map also stops working after changing the page.

Should I call refresh page?

[Sandbox link](http://viva.dyndns.org/restaurants/1)

Markup is as following:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" id="rest-header">
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-role="button" id="filter-btn" class="ui-btn-left">Filter</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="search" name="search"value="" data-theme="d" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#" data-role="button" id="map-btn" class="ui-btn-right">Map</a></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /header -->
```

Comment: you should post two questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would suggest using jQuery 1.6.4 as jQM only supports this version for 1.0

Your problem is you're adding a back button when navigating to another page, this is causing an overlap of both the filter and back button.

Removing the `data-add-back-btn="true"` attribute should solve the issue

Comment: Thank you Phill. Removing data-add-back-btn resolved the problem. Can you suggest solution for the second issue?

Answer (score 1):

For map button you should use live event binding or delegation so that it works for dynamic content. Instead of

```
$( "#map-btn" ).bind( "click", function(event, ui) { ... });
```

try

```
$(document).on('click', '#map-btn', function() {
    // ...
})
```

For filter button I can see the `Back` button under the `Filter` one, so you want to get rid of the Back button since you don't need it right there. You can remove `data-add-back-btn="true"` attribute.

Comment: thank you. removing data-add-back-btn solved the first problem. However, live binding did not help.